# how to change the button text in extjs 4.2.2 row editor?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

In earlier version of extjs we have the initEditor to override the config of row editor plugin.

In 4.2.2 we do not have initEditor , could some one please tell me how we can override configuration in 4.2.2 to update the button text.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var editor = new Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor({ 
saveText : 'My Save Button Text';, 
cancelText: 'My Cancel Button Text', 
clicksToEdit: 1, //this changes from the default double-click activation to single click activation 
errorSummary: false //disables display of validation messages if the row is invalid 
});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO :) Would you be so kind and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask